# ActionScript error: Compile Time Composite not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

I have been frustrated with this simple piece of code for quite some time now. I am just about to give up. Pretty much I am trying to make two objects react when they hit together, however I constantly get this error:

```
    Scene 1, Layer 'hero', Frame 1, Line 27 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: hit.
```

[image: Action Script] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/i883j.jpg)![idk]
[image: Action Script] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbZsh.jpg)![idk]
This is the Class file (that I am sure I am doing something wrong in to):
[image: Action Script] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPHhL.jpg)![idk]

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. With that said, one or more of the following may be causing your issue:

In File `->` ActionScript Settings, you may have a value that is greater than `1` for this field:

[image]

Similarly, you may have unchecked this field 'Export in frame 1' when creating your symbol.

[image]

If the former, your symbol `hit` will not be available until your SWF has reached the frame that you entered. If the latter, your symbol `hit` will not be available until your SWF passes over a frame that you have placed it on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line:

```
var hit:hit = new hit();
```

You have a conflict of class name and instance, rename local variable and use it everywhere:

```
var hit1:hit = new hit();
```